# IE specific: getting rid of scrollbars

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have two divs like this

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 500px; overflow:auto">
         <div style="position:absolute; top:0;left:0;width:100%">
         </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem in IE is Scrollbars start to appear unnecessarily for the outer div. Even when i have specified the inner div's width to be 100% it extends more than it is supposed to. Works fine in Firefox, Chrome. IE is causing problems.

Comment: This won't display anything. Isn't there more into the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `overflow:auto` property from outer div

Comment: The inner div can grow vertically. in that case i want scrollbars. overflow-x does not work in IE

Comment: Otherwise it won't work in IE. My suggestion would be to make sure, that inner div fits the size.

Comment: Take a look at overflow-y:auto, but i don't guarantee it will work in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a `margin-right:-1px` for IE only using ConditionalComments ( apply it to the AP'd el )